# While loop keeps continuing, without a loop it works

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to simulate a sort of Panini book, with opening packages (4 random cards) till I have had all numbers.
My problem is when I try it within a loop, the loop keeps continuing till infinitive. While doing it without a loop it just works.

**My code, when doing it without a loop**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

cards = list(range(1, 11))
print("List of all cards:", cards)

choosecard = random.choices(cards, k=4)
deletecard = [i for i in cards if i not in choosecard] 
print ("After 1 packages : " + str(deletecard))

choosecard2 = random.choices(cards, k=4)
deletecard2 = [i for i in deletecard if i not in choosecard2] 
print ("After 2 packages : " + str(deletecard2))

choosecard3 = random.choices(cards, k=4)
deletecard3 = [i for i in deletecard2 if i not in choosecard3] 
print ("After 3 packages : " + str(deletecard3))
```

Now I want to loop this because I want to use much more cards.
Therefore I thought of this:

**Loop example**

```
packagesopened = 0

while len(cards) > 0 :
    choosecard = random.choices(cards, k=4)
    deletecard = [i for i in cards if i not in choosecard]
    packagesopened +=1
    print(packagesopened)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You don't change the length of `cards` anywhere in your loop. So `len(cards)` will never change, and won't evaluate to `0` unless it started out evaluating to `0`.

Comment: Change `deletecard` to `cards`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How would that work? `packagesopened` just counts the number of iterations, what would the end test be?

Comment: @Barmar, I think he was implying that you'd also change the condition to something of the sort: `while packagesopened < 10:...`

Comment: @mypetlion Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Barmar this helped me, thanks!

Comment: @BrianJoseph Perhaps, but the list comprehension looks like he's trying to remove cards and stop when the list is empty, he just made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I never changed the cards list, so the condition stayed true forever.

Thanks for pointing this out, @Carcigenicate and @Mypetlion and @Barmar.

Changing deletecard to cards was the solution.